# simple marshalling unmarshalling objects

Tags: delphi, json, serialization, marshalling, unmarshalling

json support is one of the new features of delphi 2009 and delphi 2010. I want to know if it's there any simple function to marshalling/unmarshalling directly between string and object like in superobject library.

Example:

```
MyKnownObject := FromJSON('{name:"francis", surname:"lee"}');
```

Comment: I know there's built-in support for JSON marshalling in D2010, but I'm not sure exactly how it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unserialize a string directly to a `TJSONObject`

```
var
  ConvertFrom: String;
  JSON: TJSONObject;
  StringBytes: TBytes;
  I: Integer;
begin
  ConvertFrom := '{"name":"somebody on SO","age":"123"}';
  StringBytes := TEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(ConvertFrom);
  JSON := TJSONObject.Create;
  try
    JSON.Parse(StringBytes, 0);
    Assert(JSON.ToString = ConvertFrom, 'Conversion test');
    Memo1.Lines.Add(JSON.ToString);

    for I := 0 to JSON.Size - 1 do
      Memo1.Lines.Add(JSON.Get(I).JsonString.Value + 
         ' : ' + JSON.Get(I).JsonValue.Value);

  finally
    JSON.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 2):

See [here](http://wings-of-wind.com/2009/08/19/rad-studio-2010-review-11-datasnap/). Bellow is snipped the interesting part:

```
procedure TForm13.Button4Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  LContact: TContact;
  oMarshaller: TJSONMarshall;
  crtVal: TJSONValue;
begin
  LContact:=TContact.Create; //our custom class
  LContact.Name:='wings-of-wind.com';
  LContact.Age:=20; //fill with some data
  oMarshaller:=TJSONMarshal.Create(TJSONConverter.Create); //our engine
  try
    crtVal:=oMarshaller.Marshal(LContact); //serialize to JSON
    Memo1.Text:=crtVal.ToString; //display
  finally //cleanup
    FreeAndNil(LContact);
    FreeAndNil(oMarshaller);
  end;
end;
```

Also you can see [here](http://blogs.embarcadero.com/adrian/2009/08/19/json-types-for-server-methods-in-datasnap-2010/) a more complicated example by Adrian Andrei (the DataSnap architect) as well as an example of custom marshaling [here](http://www.danieleteti.it/?p=146).

Comment: And what about unmarshalling?

Comment: @Francis unmarshalling is discussed in the linked articles.

Comment: @skamradt examples unmarshalls from TJsonValue, not from string.

Comment: First link is broken.

Comment: Note to self (and to others): there is a TJSONMarshal/TJSONUnMarshal class also defined in REST.JsonReflect. Don't use that, use the class in DBXJSONReflect instead!

Comment: The code in the linked article is obsolete - does not compile of Delphi XE7